# How to select a subset of variables from a large dimensional dataset for Gaussian Process Regression?

Tags: gaussian-process

I am currently working on GPR(gaussian process regression) on a large dimensional input dataset(around 300). I am pretty sure that some of these variables have weak correlation with target output. If I use a RBF(radial basis function) as a kernel function then since each input variable will be treated equally so these irrelevant input will destroy my GP model.

I've tried ARD but since my dataset is too huge it is very slow and seems never converge to a local minimum. Is there any better idea to select relevant variables in a GP model?

Comment: "ARD" = "Automatic Relevance Determination"?

Comment: @whuber yes exactly. And I find ARD for a Large dimensional dataset is not a good idea...